# Create Alert dialog within a React Native function?

Tags: ios, reactjs, dialog, react-native, alert

In my React-native app, I have a screen where when the user presses a button to submit an answer, I want an alert dialog to appear telling them whether the answer is correct or incorrect. So, I am calling a function in the `onPress` method of the `TouchableHighlight` button, and within that function I specify the alert dialog. However, this causes the Alert dialog to reappear over and over, as the function is continuously called in each frame. How can I get the function to only be called once?

Relevant code:
render function

```
render: function() {                    
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{this.state.title}</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight style = {styles.button}
                    onPress={this.onSubmitPressed()}
                    underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
                    <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>SUBMIT</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
},
```

Validation function:

```
onSubmitPressed: function() {
    if (this.checkSolution) {
        Alert.alert(
            'Alert title',
            "Correct!"
        );
    }
    else {
        Alert.alert(
            'Alert title',
            "Incorrect!"
        );
    }
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling onSubmitPressed in your render function. Change `onPress={this.onSubmitPressed()}` to `onPress={this.onSubmitPressed}` (note the missing parentheses).

Comment: That did it, thanks! Why does removing the parentheses change the behavior?

Comment: With the parentheses present you pass the result of the call to onPress not the function itself. But what you really want is to pass the function. That's what happens without the parentheses.